sometimes tx.gasprice fails in sepolia, why?
I have this simple test contract to try to understand why sometiemes when I call getGasPrice() transacion fails:
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.26;

contract TesterGas {
    uint256 public gasResult;
    uint256 public normalTest;

    event GasPriceLogged(uint256 gasPrice);

    function getGasPrice() public {
        gasResult = tx.gasprice;
        emit GasPriceLogged(gasResult);
    }

    function normalCall(uint256 testNumber) public {
        normalTest = testNumber;
    }
}

you can check in sepolia network, that sometimes transacition pass and sometimes fail. Why???
contract: 0x685d5b268acFCa884fd828247aeC5E94664aEAF4

All I see is that it failed once because it ran out of gas

This is related to the gasLimit you passed in when submitting the transaction. There are 4 transactions in the contract:

【 Fail 】0x9d5c31c2a52ac6b82e4bb937bb163d08379bec4f33b7060f4cb4958c374d2d3b：Gas Limit & Usage by Txn: 37,569 | 37,569 (100%)
【Success】0x9f6f5de0cad0e3137d714cbb0bad4dfc8168b43c63a03219fe334d354048cdbb：Gas Limit & Usage by Txn:
44,985 | 44,606 (99.16%)
【Success】0xa6ad23922a16a25276643caa46a0fe4595872fe8b7b3020f06f89699516b3496：Gas Limit & Usage by Txn:
41,511 | 27,506 (66.26%)
【Success】0x11990f1467de0b421a981f5a335c32b63348c46a5332a959d099b779d3c581e2：Gas Limit & Usage by Txn:
41,511 | 27,506 (66.26%)

As you can see, the Gas Limit of a successful transaction is not fixed, but it needs to be at least 41511, although the minimum gas used is 27506, but that will be refunded to you after success, so increasing the gaslimit will not be a problem. Even if you give more, evm will refund the extra gas.
